# Nextjs Clerk Webhook shows no response

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, clerk

I have integrated clerk authentication in my nextjs app. Now I need to save the users in MongoDB through clerk webhook. I have already hosted my application to vercel, added `${vercel_site}/api/webhook` endpoint in clerk, picked up the clerk webhook key and added it to `.env.local` but so far nothing is working. In clerk, I am getting the message:

> *This endpoint has not received any messages yet*.

There are no errors in the console, the application seems to be working fine but I am not getting any response from clerk. What might be the problem?

**api/webhook/route.js**

```
import { Webhook } from "svix";
import { headers } from "next/headers";
import { createOrUpdateUser } from "../../lib/controllers/user.controller.js";

export async function POST(req) {
  // You can find this in the Clerk Dashboard -> Webhooks -> choose the webhook
  const WEBHOOK_SECRET = process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET;

  if (!WEBHOOK_SECRET) {
    throw new Error(
      "Please add WEBHOOK_SECRET from Clerk Dashboard to .env or .env.local"
    );
  }

  // Get the headers
  const headerPayload = headers();
  const svix_id = headerPayload.get("svix-id");
  const svix_timestamp = headerPayload.get("svix-timestamp");
  const svix_signature = headerPayload.get("svix-signature");

  // If there are no headers, error out
  if (!svix_id || !svix_timestamp || !svix_signature) {
    return new Response("Error occured -- no svix headers", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  // Get the body
  const payload = await req.json();
  const body = JSON.stringify(payload);

  // Create a new Svix instance with your secret.
  const wh = new Webhook(WEBHOOK_SECRET);

  let evt;

  // Verify the payload with the headers
  try {
    evt = wh.verify(body, {
      "svix-id": svix_id,
      "svix-timestamp": svix_timestamp,
      "svix-signature": svix_signature,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error verifying webhook:", err);
    return new Response("Error occured", {
      status: 400,
    });
  }

  // Handle the event
  const eventType = evt?.type;

  if (eventType === "user.created" || eventType === "user.updated") {
    const { id, first_name, last_name, profile_image_url, email_addresses } =
      evt?.data;

    try {
      await createOrUpdateUser(
        id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        profile_image_url,
        email_addresses,
      );

      return new Response("User is created or updated", {
        status: 200,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error creating or updating user:", err);
      return new Response("Error occured", {
        status: 500,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**user.controller.js**

```
import User from '../models/Users.model.js';
import { connectToDB } from '../mongo.js';

 export const createOrUpdateUser = async(id, first_name, last_name, profile_image_url,      email_addresses) => {
 try{
    await connectToDB();

    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { clerkId: id },
        {
          $set: {
            firstName: first_name,
            lastName: last_name,
            profilePhoto: profile_image_url,
            email: email_addresses[0].email_address,
          },
        },
        { upsert: true, new: true } // if user doesn't exist, create a new one
      );
  
      await user.save();
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
}
```

**Connection to database**

```
 import mongoose from "mongoose";

 let isConnected = false;

 export const connectToDB = async () => {
     mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);

   if (isConnected) {
     console.log("Database is connected");
   } else {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_STRING, {
        dbName: "Users",
        useNewUrlParser: true,
         useUnifiedTopology: true,
      });
      isConnected = true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
};
```

In route.js, I tried to `console.log(svix_id, svix_timestamp, svix_signature)` but again no response. This makes me to wonder, is this file even getting called in the first place. I also tried to catch any errors in case the POST request fails but there is no error so far.

```
catch (err) {
      console.error("Error creating or updating user:", err);
      return new Response("Error occured", {
        status: 500,
      });
    }
```

Comment: For anyone having this problem in the future, just make sure you log the payload that you are sending to clerk webhooks. If the payload object has the wrong data then it will not go through and you will get a failed response. Also check your database for any wrong connections.